# ¿Cómo puedo crear un sidebar con jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

No entiendo que falla me da errores como que el símbolo `$` no está definido y demases, cuando es código que ya por desesperación he tenido que copiar y pegar de tutoriales.

Lo que me gustaría hacer, por si no se entiende mediante el código, es conseguir que pulsando/clicando sobre toggle-btn se abra un menú desplegable, que en este caso no es mas que un cuadro azul (cuadrolat).

Mi código (hay que pulsar en "Página completa" para ver el menu desplazándose):

```js
$(".toggle-btn").on("click", function() {
  $(".cuadrolat").toggleClass("cuadro");
})
```

```css
* {
  padding: "0px";
  margin: "0px";
}

.cuadrolat {
  position: fixed;
  left: -350px;
  top: 200px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 400px;
  background: blue;
  transition: 0.8s all;
}

.cuadro {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 200px;
  background: blue;
}

.toggle-btn {
  position: absolute;
  left: 230px;
  top: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="estilos.css">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width initial-scale=1.0">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="cuadrolat">
  </div>
  <div class="toggle-btn">
    <span>&#9776</span>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Edit: acabo de probar el sidebar a través de la opción que permite esta misma pagina y lo curioso es que funciona, pero lo raro es que en chrome no lo hace y me da problemas en la consola.

Comment: El error de "el símbolo $ no está definido" ocurre porque no se está cargando jQuery de forma correcta, o porque se está ejecutando código de jQuery antes de cargar la biblioteca de jQuery. Trata de editar la pregunta para poner el código tal y como lo tienes en el sitio que falla para que podamos ver el problema. ¿Cómo se cargan los .js? ¿en qué orden? ¿qué errores recibes en la consola? etc.

Answer (score 0):

Si estás cargando tu jquery al inicio de tu código, asegúrate de usar $(document).ready(), de esta forma aseguras que tu script se cargue `después` de cargar el contenido.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $(".toggle-btn").on("click", function() {
     $(".cuadrolat").toggleClass("cuadro");
   })  
});
```

Por otro lado es recomendable colocar los scripts justo `antes del cierre de la etiqueta body`